Should you be able to forward/pass a local Yubikey through ssh to the remote as a connected hardware device?
From a security perspective, would it defeat the purpose of a Yubikey if I could insert it into my local device, access a server with (for example) a simple username & password, and then authenticate on the remote server with my local yubikey? Or is this possible not encouraged, but not exactly something that Yubikeys are specifically designed to prevent?
I have been trying to do something like this for a little now, but the more I try to make it work the more it seems like it would defeat the point of the something-you-have security key, I think.
I can forward the local SSH Agent to the remote, and then it seems like the Yubikey/credential passes through to the remote server. But what I am specifically thinking of is when the Yubikey asks for a physical touch, or if you try to create a new ed25519-sk keypair on the remote server using it while it is inserted into your local computer.
Thanks!
